# Android Button not clickable when above RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have an android widget and I can't get the first Button to work (see layout.xml below). It just doesn't respond if i tap it.

My other buttons inside the layout are all working fine.

If I put the LinearLayout with the first button below the relativelayout (they both have weight=0.5) then the button inside the LinearLayout will start working all of a sudden but the buttons inside the relativelayout stop working.

Why is changing my layout.xml effecting some buttons to work properly and other buttons stop working and vice versa (like described above)? Any ideas please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >


<!--  LEFT SIDE OF THE VIEW (WIDTH 50%) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_p_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >


    <!--  FIRST BUTTON -->
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/my_webcam_img"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


<!--  RIGHT SIDE OF THE VIEW (WIDTH 50%) -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <!--  WRAPPER BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--  WRAPPER FOR POSITIONING THE BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="8dp">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <!--  WRAPPER FOR POSITIONING THE BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <!--  WRAPPER -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <!--  TOP NAVIGATION -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#eb690b" >


            <!--  BUTTON PREVIOUS CAM -->
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/previous_cam_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


            <!--  HEADER LABEL -->
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text ="ABC HEADER"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous_cam_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_cam_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />


            <!--  BUTTON NEXT CAM -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_cam_button"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/next"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />   

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />



        <!--  BOTTOM TOOLBAR -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <!--  BUTTON SYNC -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sync_button"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
                    android:text="" />


                <!--  BUTTON SETTINGS -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/settings"
                    android:text="" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't respond"?

Comment: Did you add your `onClickListeners`?

Comment: Thank you, I had an onClickListener in my widget provider class onUpdate, but I forgot that I later set a widget configuration class which won't call onUpdate. I refactored my code, wrote some initializiation function that can be used from widget provider and widget configuration classes and it works :-)